# conditional marginal effect at the mean is the same as the average of the conditional marginal effect in the Linear Probability model?

Tags: probability, logistic, logit, probit, marginal-effect

I know that MEM and AVE is rather different in a probit and logit model, but it is true that these two values are the same in the Linear Probability model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are the same, and equal to the raw coefficients from your model. This is because the linear probability model is a linear model.